# Overriding default template for specific nodes in a databound (XML/XPath) TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, xaml, datatemplate

TL;DR up front: I would like to use a "default" HierarchicalDataTemplate for all but a specific few nodes in a WPF TreeView. These nodes come from an XMLDocument and are not fully known until runtime. Is there a way to do this?

At runtime, I am analyzing specific parts of a system, and building an XML document that I'm then binding to a TreeView like so:

```
MyTree.DataContext = MyXMLDocument;
```

This is my WPF declaration of the TreeView:

```
<TreeView x:Name="MyTree" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, XPath=/Analysis}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GenericElementWithChildren}"/>
```

The template starts like this...

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="GenericElementWithChildren" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=child::node()}">
```

So for example, I might have some long XML document about different aspects of the analysis I just ran and I'd like some particular element like "Disk" or "Proprietary Foo Service" to have a special template because it should be displayed nicely, while everything else just gets a generic template.

I've thought about using a DataTemplateSelector but it seems like there must be a better way. I'm not even sure how I'd do that for XML. Do any of you smarter folks have any wisdom to impart, or am I stuck figuring out how to write a DataTemplateSelector against XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataTemplate` and `HierarchicalDataTemplate` also have a `DataType` property. 
When you remove the `x:Key` and supply a `DataType`, these Templates are implicit. So you can define your different templates as implicit and they will be used automatically, as long as you don't supply a `ItemTemplate` or `ItemTemplateSelector` on the inital `TreeView`.

```
<HierachicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ProprietaryFooService}">
```

Personally i try to avoid that, because this also means that other controls that can show your data are using these Templates aswell. Imo the best would be to use a `DataTemplateSelector`, especially when you deal with the same types that you need to show in different ways.

**Edit:**
Sorry i missed that you are using Xpath. I guess it will not work there. I will leave this answer here, but can't guarantee that it suits your needs. Maybe it helps in another way anyway.

Comment: Hmm... If you have a better way than what I'm doing, I'm definitely interested to see it. I'm new to binding to XML.